# Validate configuration before or after build

Tags: typescript, craco

I have a React app that uses different configuration based on some env variables.

Configuration is always imported as

```js
import config from '@config';
```

Before build, `tsconfig.json` and webpack are constructed with a JS script such that `@config` resolves to the appropriate path.

However, the config file might import other files, e.g

```js
import baseConfig from './baseConfig';
import Config from './types';

const config:Config = {
    ...baseConfig,
    key: "value"
}
```

What I would like to do is to check if of the fields in the generated configuration are set to default values and raise some warnings about that.

However, I cannot do it in my JS script, as after importing the file `require("./config.ts")` I get:

```
import baseConfig from './baseConfig';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

How can I build just this file so I would be able to check the values?

Comment: It's generally better to validate your configuration before building your application using a linter, pre-build script, or build-time validation tool.